# ssh + nohup does not work

Tags: background-process, ssh, nohup

I'm trying to run a program over SSH that keeps running when I disconnect. [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29172/309308) gave me the following command:

```
nohup sleep 30 > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. I login (`ssh -Y`) to a remote bash shell and execute it, disconnect, and come back within 30 seconds, but `jobs` shows nothing and the `foo` files also show nothing. Is there any other way I can run background jobs over ssh after I logout?

Comment: The sleep command does not generate any output, so you should expect the output files to remain empty.

Comment: Oh, and `jobs` only shows processes that are descendants of the current shell. Try with `ps | grep sleep` instead.

Comment: This does not seem a question related to ssh.

Comment: Question is a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh user@server "echo /usr/run/my/job | at now +1 min"
```

Answer (score 1):

`jobs` won't show anything if you spawned the process in another shell; the first line of its man page description is:

> The jobs utility shall display the status of jobs that were started in the current shell environment

So you could ssh to the computer, `sleep 30 &`, and ssh from another window, and `jobs` still wouldn't show anything in that other window even though the process is obviously still running. The command you have works; try using `ps` or `pgrep` to check for it instead (e.g. `pgrep sleep`)