# service killed at ssh hangup

Tags: bash, ssh, signals, nohup, tomcat

If I use `ssh` to run some command in background, that command gets killed as soon an ssh hangs up:

```
ssh localhost -t "bash -c '(for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do sleep \$i;done)&'"; ps x|grep sleep
```

This will not show any running sleep process. (But it would, if I do the ps inside the ssh command.)

However if I manually log in, run it it background and logout, the command keeps running.

```
ssh localhost
bash -c '(for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do sleep $i;done)&';exit
ps x|grep sleep
```

Why is the first command killed? Why not the second one?

(NB: This problem arose when I tried to start a service with `service tomcat start` which worked fine after a manual login, but no service was running after invoking directly in the ssh command.)

---

No, this is not a duplicate of [ssh + nohup does not work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27220/ssh-nohup-does-not-work). I am not talking about nohup and I am not trying to use `jobs` instead of `ps`.

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate of the mentioned question at all!

Answer (score 1):

It's your double quotes in the command

```
ssh localhost -t "bash -c '(for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do sleep $i;done)&'"
```

The shell which you are calling the command from tries to replace `$i`, before the whole commandline is executed. Usualy `$i` is not defined so it is interpreted to

```
ssh localhost -t "bash -c '(for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do sleep ;done)&'"
```

which runs through with 5 error messages saying

```
sleep: missing operand
Try 'sleep --help' for more information.
```

The solution is to mask the `$` or to use outer single quotes:

```
ssh localhost -t "bash -c '(for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do sleep \$i;done)&'"
ssh localhost -t 'bash -c '\''(for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do sleep $i;done)&'\'
```

Comment: Oops, you are right. I was trying to set up a easy example and built in a totaly different bug. thanks for pointing out. Fixed this above. Now it shows the problem correctly.